# Sending continuous logs from one application to Another in C#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two application's running independently of one another. At present, ApplicationSend is web-based and ApplicationReceive is desktop-based, but tomorrow it might be the opposite. There are no Multiple UI.

The ApplicationSend keep logging info into the database or Text file. when the ApplicationSend logs info, it needs to display in ApplicationReceive at the same time without any delay.

The ApplicationReceive uses rest API to display the data.

I have two questions:

1. How this can be achieved in C#. Please note the application's are
   completely unaware of each other. Also one application can be
   Windows and other can be web.
2. When the REST API Display 10 logs, next time should it query for all
   the logs or only the updated logs?. Ideally it should be only
   updated logs. But how would one get the updated logs

Comment: Maybe SignalR can help you.

Comment: "one application can be windows and other can be web"...is this just badly worded or are you implying that this is interchangeable - i.e. today ApplicationSend is web-based and ApplicationReceive is desktop-based, but tomorrow it might be the opposite? Do you have multiple GUI clients for each application? It's not clear.

Comment: Anyway unless you simply open a direct socket connection between the two, I doubt you'll ever achieve it without _any_ delay. Right now the receiver has to poll the database for changes. Do that too often and you'll have horrible performance problems. P.S. If you only want to query for "updated logs" you'd have to tell the system the ID of the last log received. Maybe you'd be better with some sort of event-driven messaging system, the sort of thing implemented by RabbitMQ and similar products.

Comment: Define `without any delay`? You know that all communication is bound by speed of light and whatever the distance between your applications, there will be a minimum delay that required for data to travel between the apps. So given there is a physical limitation, how much of a delay you'd accept? a couple seconds? 5-15 seconds OK?

Comment: Both application unaware each other how you know one application generate data that should be populated in second application , i Think there should be at least one table common. etc if one application generate  request then use some api to push data into second application db & then populate it in request queue.